How can I find in which source .scss files is this compiled CSS-style configured?
There is a style in the compiled .css file:
media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .SomePage_title .SomeSection_headline {

How can I quickly find in which of the 40 source .scss files this is configured?
I am currently using PhpStorm with regexp search:
SomePage(.*\n*.*)*_title(.*\n*.*)*SomeSection(.*\n*.*)*_headline

but the search is always very complicated and long, especially when mixins are used.

Not sure about the IDE. But your browser should be able to tell where the source is -- you need to compile with source maps if I'm not mistaken. https://www.sitepoint.com/using-source-maps-debug-sass-chrome/
